# Use takeWhile operator with different Observable source as a flag

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I want to unsubscribe from an observable by using another observable source.

```
stop$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
source: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
this.source.pipe(takeWhile(this.stop$ === false)).subscribe()
```

Can I do that with takeWhile operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

takeWhile operator emits values until provided expression is false. Predicate function should return `true` or a `false` value, so you cannot use a subject here (although you can do some modifications and use BehaviourSubject and similar but its not recommended)

**EDITED:**

Better solution would be to use takeUntil operator in a way like:

```
this.source
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(
      this.stop$.pipe(filter(val => !val))
    )
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Or you can extract an Observable:

```
unsubscribe$: Observable<boolean> = this.stop$.pipe(filter(val => !val));

this.source
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: I phrased my question badly but this is the answer I was looking for. However, I get `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Subject<boolean>'`.

Comment: Yeah, its when you are typing directly from the head. I will edit my post.